# How to use ''MATHEMATICA'' to compute the number of connected induced subgraphs in any input graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

An induced subgraph of a simple graph G is a graph that contains a nonempty subset of vertices of G together with all edges incident with them in G.

Comment: Can you give sample input in Mathematica code (eg a simple graph) and the desired output?

Comment: [NeighborhoodGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeighborhoodGraph.html)?